# Node Express Session is not working. Getting req.session.user undefined for next request

Tags: node.js, session, angular, express-session

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express_session({
    secret: 'abcdefg',
    proxy: true,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}));

app.post("/login", function(req, res, next) {

                    var session = req.session;
                    session.user = 'dadsvadsvhaha';

});
```

Here is my code. I have used this previously in the same way. But now its not working, unable to figure it out.

Comment: The problem is with angular 2 response headers

Answer (score 0):

I tried following and works fine for me. It just increments value to request.session.views variable if existing or sets request.session.views = 1

```
// Use the session middleware
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))

// Access the session as req.session
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
var sess = req.session
if (sess.views) {
    sess.views++
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.write('<p>views: ' + sess.views + '</p>')
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (sess.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
    res.end()
} else {
    sess.views = 1
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
}});
```

Which version of Node.Js are you using?